# Expression method, how to implement greater than

Tags: c#, .net, predicate

I have this piece of code :

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
 Expression.Call(
    Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "MyProperty"),
    "Equals", null,
    Expression.Constant(Convert.ToInt32("MyValue")))
```

Is there a way to implement `>`, `>=`, `<` and `<=` instead of `Equals` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want methods like [`Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.greaterthanorequal). If you're trying to implement `==` I would use [`Expression.Equal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.equal) too, rather than generating a method call to the (polymorphic) `Equals` method.